# Commuting of the exponentials of matrices $A$ and $B$ implies commuting of $A$ and $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices of the same size. It well known that $\mathrm{e}^{tA}\mathrm{e}^{tB}=\mathrm{e}^{t(A+B)}$, for every $t\in\mathbb R$, if and only if $AB=BA$.

I have the following question: Does $\mathrm{e}^{A}\mathrm{e}^{B}=\mathrm{e}^{A+B}$ imply that $AB=BA$?

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ real matrices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not. There is considerable literature on this, see [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2013-141-03/S0002-9939-2012-11396-6/) (available for free, it seems), which has a counterexample (of two matrices whose exponentials commute and are not even simulataneously triangularizable. (in case the link does not work:
Author: Clément de Seguins Pazzis 
Journal: Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 141 (2013), 763-774 
)

Comment: I couldn't access the paper without subscription. But I found it [on the arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4420).

Comment: See also:  C.W. Huﬀ, On pairs of matrices (of order two) A, B satisfying the condition $\mathrm{e}^{A+B}=\mathrm{e}^A\mathrm{e}^B\ne\mathrm{e}^B\mathrm{e}^A$, Rend. Circ. Math. Palermo 2 (1953).